# ui:field and class to <td>/<tr> in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I am using UIBinder to make a widget.

ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
<ui:style>
.back { background-color: Skyblue; }
</ui:style>

    <g:HTML>
    <div ui:field="somediv">
        <tr class="{style.back}">
        <td>The background is NOT Skyblue</td>
        </tr>   
    </div>
    </g:HTML>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

java

```
public class Test extends Composite {

    interface TestUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTML, Test> {}
    private static TestUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(TestUiBinder.class);


    public Test() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
```

Entrypoint:

```
public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        RootPanel.get().add(test);
}
```

The text does not get skyblue color..
However if i add a span element inside my td and do class="{style.back}", that works.
Why?

Also, if i try to add a ui:field to my td/tr tags i get a crash:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at  
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at  
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183) at
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:5
10) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352) at
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: 
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): this.removeAttribute is not a function
```

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the fact that you're using `<tr>` as the child of a `<div>`.

Comment: No.
Tried removing the div, no result.

Comment: @Frederik: `<tr>` can only occur as the child of a `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` or `<tbody>`.

Comment: Thank you.
Adding a <table> around this did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chris Lercher suggested in the comments, adding a table around the tr's solved the problem. Closing question..